# Property 'insertId' does not exist on type 'Boolean | (Partial<TEvents> & { insertId?: number | undefined; })'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a code in javascript and I'm trying to convert it to typescript

```js
route.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await events.delete(req.params.id);
        res.send({ success: true, data: { id: result.insertId } });
```

this piece of code used to work just fine in js , but now that I have converted it to typescript I get this error on insertId

`Property 'insertId' does not exist on type 'Boolean | (Partial<TEvents> & { insertId?: number | undefined; })'. Property 'insertId' does not exist on type 'Boolean'.ts(2339)`

I tried to solve the problem by adding insertId on TEvents type but it didn't work

here is my Event model:

```js
import { Model } from './Model';
type TEvents = {
    total    ?:string;
    insertId ?:any;
    status   ?:any;
    id       ?:any;
}
export class Events extends Model<TEvents> {

    constructor() {
        super('events');
    }

}
```

> any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the fulfillment value from `delete`'s promise is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types). It's either a `Boolean` or a `Partial<TEvents> & { insertId?: number | undefined; }`. `insertId` only exists on one part of that union, so in order to use it safely, you have to check to see what you got, a `Boolean` or a `Partial<TEvents> & { insertId?: number | undefined; }`.

You can do that with a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types), for instance:

```typescript
route.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const result = await events.delete(req.params.id);
        if ("insertId" in result) {
            res.send({ success: true, data: { id: result.insertId } });
        } else {
            // What you got either was a boolean or was a `Partial<TEvents>`
            // without an `insertId` property
        }
```

---

Side note: It's odd to use `Boolean` (rather than `boolean`, in lowercase) as a type, so it may be worth looking at the definition of `events.delete` and seeing if you really meant to use `Boolean` rather than `boolean`. More [in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#about-number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object).